# java.lang.AbstractMethodError for Mulitple SCM Plugin Jenkins and GITBLIT

Tags: git, jenkins, repository

This is the first time, I am using online platform to get help. So please bear with me.

I am using 
Jenkins Version 1.562
Multiple SCM Plugin Version Latest(0.4)
GITBlit for repository.

Trying to work with multiple repositories and came across this plugin. Downloaded installed and implemented in Jenkins Job. But when trying to execute this job getting following exception

> FATAL: null java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1251)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
>     at
>   jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1704)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is 1.610  which may help

You are [advised](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitblit/qxUrke6X_6Y) to use the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) for blit  (which needs Jenkins v1.568 at this time)

If you are using a Blit plugin (I couldn't find one) please update your answer with the link to it

Comment: Thanks, But I don't really have an option to upgrade Jenkins for now. I am using GIT Plugin. 

Can you please suggest any other method by which I can achieve multiple repository working on jenkins.